# How to convert html data to xml file

Tags: html, xslt

I have requirement like i need to create an xml file from html input .

It has a huge html data where i need to convert to xml format which is usefu to parse with other files .

### Input Html

```
<html>
<tr>
<td>SG 874/SG 322</td>
<td>Agartala</td>
<td>Chennai</td>
<td>16:30</td>
<td>23:15</td>
<td>Kolkata</td>
<td>Daily</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SG 873/SG 881</td>
<td>Agartala</td>
<td>Delhi</td>
<td>13:00</td>
<td>18:05</td>
<td>Gawahati</td>
<td>Daily</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SG  873/SG 894</td>
<td>Agartala</td>
<td>Delhi</td>
<td>13:00</td>
<td>20:40</td>
<td>Gawahati</td>
<td>Daily</td>
</tr>
</html>
```

### Sample XML Needed

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <schedules>

<Routes>
<Flgno>SG 874/SG 322</Flgno>
<org>Agartala</org>
<des>Chennai</des>
<Dept>16:30</Dept>
<Arr>23:15</Arr>
<Via>Kolkata</Via>
<frq>Daily</frq>
</Routes>

<Routes>
<Flgno>SG 873/SG 881</Flgno>
<org>Agartala</org>
<des>Delhi</des>
<Dept>13:00</Dept>
<Arr>18:05</Arr>
<Via>Gawahati</Via>
frq>Daily</frq>
</Routes>

<Routes>
<Flgno>SG  873/SG 894</Flgno>
<org>Agartala</org>
<des>Delhi</des>
<Dept>13:00</Dept>
<Arr>18:40</Arr>
<Via>Gawahati</Via>
<frq>Daily</frq>
</Routes> 
</schedules>
```

Suggest me the transformtion techniques with example

Comment: What did you try? Is your HTML valid XML - so it can be handled with an XSLT - or does it contains things that are valid in HTML but not in XML? (non-closed tags, entities like non-breakable space etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To respond to you specific question ("suggest transformation techniques") and the sample input/result you provided:

- Look at the most fundamental XSLT design pattern: [`The Identity Transformation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT)
- Furthermore, look at techniques for overriding this Identity Transformation. A quick Google search yields [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009758/xsl-identity-transform-change-value-of-an-element) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812260/how-to-override-the-values-in-an-xml-using-xsl) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008930/selecting-nodes-with-the-default-namespace) (all from this website).

Should you still have issues once you've attempted to apply these principles, let us know.